# How do I use grep while keeping the original text color?

Tags: grep, pipe, colors, escape-characters

For example, I have a output:

```
Hello, this is the output.
```

(let's say that for example `hello` is colored red, and `the` is colored green, and `output` is colored purple).

Now, let's say that this is the output of a command named `x`.

If I use this command, the output becomes white:

```
x | grep hello
```

I've read that one could use `grep --color=always`. However, this changes the color to highlight the result I searched for instead of keeping the original line colors.

I want to keep the original line colors. How do I use grep while keeping them?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could do this,

```
 x | grep --color=never hello
```

To quickly test it, you can do,

```
ls -l /etc/ --color=always | grep --color=never .
```

Comment: The high amount of upvotes suggest this is the answer; but it is a partial answer that doesn't work in general. It works for ls just fine though.

Comment: The complete answer is that you probably _also_ need to disable color in the preceding program. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63456696/2954547 for how to do this with Git. The answer here shows how to do it with `ls`.

Comment: Doesn't work with ls for me.

Answer (score 15):

Just a quick hack: when grep is sending output to a pipe, it also commutes to no-changing-color mode

```
x | grep hello | cat
```